# Algebraic geometry books that can be read without knowing schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want an algebraic geometry book on some certain special topic in algebraic geometry that can be read without knowing schemes but motivates me towards schemes and may be makes me learn schemes on the way after some time.Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/undergraduate-algebraic-geometry-textbook-recomendations - this might be of help.

Answer (score 4):

There are two readable books that comes too mind.

The first is Joe Harris' "[Introduction to Algebraic Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387977163)". It is stuffed with examples, although some of them can be difficult. He requires that you know basic commutative algebra (that is: you should be familiar with the polynomial ring in several variables).

The other book, which I personally find much more entertaining, is Miles Reid's "[Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521356628)". He again assumes very little, and finishes with a proof that on a smooth cubic surface there are 27 lines. The last chapter is a "the road ahead" chapter, in which he talks about the power of schemes, and in his own words, some "name-dropping".