# Undergrad Geometry Book

Tags: geometry, reference-request

What is a good follow-up to Stillwell's *Four Pillars of Geometry*?

Also Algebraic Geometry/ Topology sounds fun -- are there any good undergrad books on that?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/undergraduate-algebraic-geometry-textbook-recomendations

Comment: So from that link is *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms* by Cox, Litle and O'Shea, Miles Reid's *Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry*, or Bertrametti's *Lectures on Curves, Surfaces and Projective Varieties* a good follow-up to Stillwell's book (and Algebra at the level of Dummit and Foote)?

Comment: From the intro to Reid's book, I don't think I have the requisite algebra, yet.  Is there a good geometry book I can look into now that I have the basics from Stillwell down?

Comment: You should ask more specific questions, but: Reid & Szendroi's *Geometry & Topology* you might now enjoy; Hilbert & Cohn-Vossen, *Geometry and the Imagination*; chapter 3 in *Mathematics: Its Content, Methods & Meaning*...