# From algebraic master degree to algebraic geomery Phd

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, education

I am a foreign master student in algebra at the final year. I'm familar with categorical algebra and have interesting in algebraic geomery and number theory. I have learned some knowledge about scheme theory and algebraic number theory from online notes, but have not read Hartshorne yet.

I want to apply for a Phd program in algebraic geometry or arithmetic geometry in US universities. But I wonder if my background can be accepted, especailly considering my poor english skill.

My questions are:

> 1, Can my background be accepted for some good Phd programs in algebraic/arithmetic geometry?
>
> 2, Except Harvard, Princeton, Berkeley, Chicago, MIT, Stanford, Columbia etc., which have been listed in USNews, where are good Phd programs in algebraic/arithmetic geometry?
>
> 3, Is there some useful suggestions about further learning on algebraic/arithmetic geometry?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/undergraduate-algebraic-geometry-textbook-recomendations for some books on algebraic geometry

Comment: or even http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2446/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne

Comment: 1. I guess you should try?