# Complementary textbook algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I don't know where to ask this or if it is allowed to do it, so please let me know any details for further questions of this kind.

I am taking an algebraic geometry class and am using the textbook "Ideals, Varieties, and algorithms" by David Cox et. al. I was wondering if any of you had any suggested textbooks to use as complementary textbooks for this book or books that help get a deeper understanding of the basic algebraic geometry material.

Comment: A nice introductory book (maybe a bit dry) is Fulton's _Algebraic Curves_, available free from the [author's website](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf). I do think the computational stuff in the book you mention is pretty unique, though. The only book with a similar emphasis that I can think of is Schenck's _Computational Algebraic Geometry_. I think that's a bit more advanced, though.

Comment: Shafarevich, _Basic Algebraic Geometry_; Reid, _Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry_.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Have a look at the answers to the following [closely related MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the contents of Cox et al.'s book;

but a good basic introduction to algebraic geometry is Klaus Hulek - *Elementary Algebraic Geometry*, and if it can be useful for you: David S. Dummit & Richard M. Foote - *Abstract Algebra*, here you can find a little introduction to Groebner basis and other interesting material. ;)

P.S.: "Et" is a Latin word, the translation in Englis is "and"; it needs not of final point. ;D

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will look at the book!

Comment: Not at all, it's a pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might like to take a look at Joe Harris: *Algebraic Geometry*.