# Recommend guide book of algebraic geometry

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, sheaf-theory

I have a little knowledge about geometry and algebraic topology . I want to learn some basic conception and thought of algebraic geometry. Besides , I want to know main of theory of sheaves. What book I should read ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/undergraduate-algebraic-geometry-textbook-recommendations

Comment: You didn't mention any knowledge about commutative algebra. If that is lacking, then you should probably focus on that first.